# Have a template method but not expose implementation

Tags: c++, templates, header-files

I have a function in TFRuntime.h

```
class TFRuntime {
...
    template <typename T>
    Status computeXYSlice(Volume<T>* input, int zCoord, Volume<T> *output);
...
}
```

TFRuntime.cpp includes tensorflow library headers such as

```
#include <tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h>
#include <tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h>
```

I do not want to make these includes in the header since that would force anyone using TFRuntime to include them as well. However if i want the `computeXYSlice` function to allow any type, I have to include the implementation in the .h file. The implementation however requires the above mentioned tensorflow headers.

How do I get around this problem? Could I explicitly 'instantiate' only certain variants of the `computeXYSlice` function? E.g., where `T` is `float` or `int` or `double`? Or is there a better way?

Comment: If it's going to only be float, int or double, then don't template it, and just overload the function.  The implementation of those 3 overloads can then be calls into the template.

Comment: Thanks that sounds good. If I wanted to allow any type there is no going around exposing the implementation right?

Comment: 'Fraid not; that's just the way of templates.

Comment: Is the Tensorflow code templated? If not, you can provide your own wrappers and hide Tensorflow calls in a cpp file.

Comment: It is not, your solution would work for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Could I explicitly 'instantiate' only certain variants of the computeXYSlice function? E.g., where T is float or int or double?

You may, and their implementation need not be in the header. I'll get to that in a moment. But if you really want to allow *any type* then your template must be in a header. That's just how it is.

If you wish to support only a small set of types, as template instantiations, without overloading (can make a difference sometimes when doing lookup), the standard has a mechanism for *explicit template instantiation*.

Your header will look something like this...

```
class TFRuntime {
public:
    template <typename T>
    Status computeXYSlice(Volume<T>* input, int zCoord, Volume<T> *output);
};
```

... And your implementation file, will contain the explicit instatiation *definitions*, like so...

```
template <typename T>
Status TFRuntime::computeXYSlice(Volume<T>* input, int zCoord, Volume<T> *output) {
  // Implement it
}

template
Status TFRuntime::computeXYSlice(Volume<int>*, int, Volume<int>*);

template
Status TFRuntime::computeXYSlice(Volume<double>*, int, Volume<double>*);
```

You have to include the explicit instantiation definitions, otherwise your program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required. [The template function must be defined when implicit instantiation occurs, unless an explicit instantiation appears somewhere](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#7).

This is a bit cumbersome. But if your end goal is to indeed have a bunch of instantiations (as opposed to overloads), that's how you tie it all together.

Comment: Can you explain what the effect of leaving out the instantiation declarations would be? I was under the impression that the linker will sort it out (and possibly give `symbol not found` errors when you try to use template arguments for which no explicit instantiations were made in the source)? What does adding the instantiation declarations accomplish?

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Added to the answer. Your impression is correct. The linker does sort it out. But you have to explicitly instantiate a definition for the linker to find. `extern template` essentially just creates a declaration. It must still be defined somewhere.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the presence of the explicit instantiation _declarations_ is not required for correctness (assuming you do have explicit instantiation _definitions_ matching every use of the template)? I understand that missing explicit instantiation _definitions_ are UB, but I still can't tell what the explicit instantiation _declarations_ achieve in this case where the template definition is not available in other TUs.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - They are required. Sorry, I misunderstood you. [Implicit instantiation happens when the *definition is required to exist*.](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.inst#4). Since the function template is not defined, if an implicit instantation occurs, it must cause an error.

Comment: To clarify, I am talking about [this](https://godbolt.org/g/RxABwf) kind of situation, which I would consider the essence of the asked question. As far as I understand, this yields no error as your statement does not apply because the function definition is not required to exist here. Is this example safe (without explicit instantiation declarations) or am I in UB land?

Comment: @MaxLanghof - At this point I don't know. I get why this can be fine. But I can't find the wording that would confirm one way or the other. I know for sure that it has to be fine with the explicit instantiation declaration. So I would still advocate it unless I find wording to the contrary.

Comment: @MaxLanghof - Hang on. Found it. [You are in UB land](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#7).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173975/discussion-between-max-langhof-and-storyteller).

Comment: The sentence you're quoting ends with "... unless the corresponding specialization is explicitly instantiated in some translation unit". You don't need the declarations in the header, the explicit instantiations in some TU suffices.

Comment: @Barry - So no need for the explicit instantiation declaration? I'm (pleasantly) surprised. I was under the impression it was requires for all templates.

Comment: @StoryTeller Nope. No need.

Comment: The declarations may not be needed - still adding them may make sense for a totally different reason: Any user of the header would see immediately which instantiations actually exist, without having to try first...

Answer (score 3):

You can wrap the used (non-templated) Tensorflow functionality in your own header/sources file and call your wrappers from your templated code:

```
// wrapper.h:
void some_function();

// wrapper.cpp:
#include <tensorflow/...>
void some_function() { /* use tensorflow stuff here */ }

// TFRuntime.h:
#include "wrapper.h" // no inclusion of Tensorflow headers involved

template <typename T>
void some_templated_function() { 
    some_function();
}
```

Live demo: https://wandbox.org/permlink/dWRT0AEi8alylTQB

However, this solution adds code redundancy and could stop working if Tensorflow API gets changed.

Comment: If tensor flow API gets changed, *any* code relying on the unchanged API would break, so that's not an issue specific to your solution...

Answer (score 2):

I personally would just stay with the public template, sure, you'll be forced then to deliver the included headers together with your own ones, but I'd just byte the bullet in this case for leaving most possible flexibility for users of your class.

You might hide that away, at least, in a separate ".inl" or ".impl" file (doesn't solve in the sense you asked, but makes it less visible):

```
class TFRuntime
{
    template <typename T>
    Status computeXYSlice(Volume<T>* input, int zCoord, Volume<T>* output);
};

#include "TFRuntime.inl"
```

and:

```
#include <tensorflow/cc/ops/standard_ops.h>
#include <tensorflow/cc/saved_model/loader.h>

template <typename T>
Status TFRuntime::computeXYSlice(Volume<T>* input, int zCoord, Volume<T>* output)
{
    // ...
}
```

If you really want to limit the the range of data types being usable I'd do it via overloads:

```
class TFRuntime
{
public:
    Status computeXYSlice(Volume<int>* input, int zCoord, Volume<int>* output);
    Status computeXYSlice(Volume<double>* input, int zCoord, Volume<double>* output);
    Status computeXYSlice(Volume<unsigned long>* input, int zCoord, Volume<unsigned long>* output);
private:
    template <typename T>
    Status computeXYSlice(Volume<T>* input, int zCoord, Volume<T>* output);
};
```

As now the template function is private, it cannot be called from "outside", and you can safely implement it in the .cpp file (where only the required specialisations will be instantiated), together with the normal overloaded functions calling the template function (you need to provide the template parameter explicitly to prevent recursion – or give the template function a different name). Do *not* implement the overloads already in the class definition, otherwise they get inlined and you expose the template function again to other classes, requiring the implementation being available again...