# Are explicit template instantiation declarations required in the header when explicitly instantiating the definitions in the source file?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, template-specialization

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51079075/have-a-template-method-but-not-expose-implementation/51079624#51079624), the accepted answer involves a template function *declaration* in a header file which has its *definition* in the source file. To make this template function also usable in other translation units, explicit template instantiations are made in the source file for each "allowed" usage. So far this appears to me as standard practice.

The answer however also recommends placing corresponding explicit template instantiation *declarations* in the header file. I have not seen this practice before and would like to know if this is required by the standard.

Here is a small example:

**A.h**

```
struct A
{
    template<class T>
    void g(T t);
};
```

**A.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

template<class T>
void A::g(T t)
{ /* ... */ }

template void A::g(int); // Explicit instantiation of the definition.
```

**main.cpp**

```
#include "A.h"

int main()
{
    A a;
    a.g(0);
}
```

The [wording in the standard](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp#7) does not make it clear to me whether the explicit instantiation of the *declaration* is also required. This seems to primarily concern the "the definition is never instantiated explicitly, an implicit instantiation in `A.cpp` is not guaranteed to be retained" case (not depicted), but I would appreciate clarification.

Comment: I don't see how it would be/could be required. You're implicitly doing it anyway as soon as you use the function  in main.cpp. Ultimately it's a question of translation units and as soon as the one carried out of `main.cpp` sees `a.g(0);` the result is resolution and expansion to the decl-only template `A` from A.h itself, which expands as warranted  (not already done for that TU).

Comment: From my understanding, your code is ok (omitting the missing `#include "A.h"` in A.cpp).

Comment: I was checking something else, when I cam across this (albeit non-normative) example:https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/temp.over#5 I think it further helps solidify the intent of the sentence Barry highlighted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Are explicit template instantiation declarations required in the header when explicitly instantiating the definitions in the source file?

No. The rule is, from [[temp]/10](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp#10), emphasis mine:

> A function template, member function of a class template, variable template, or static data member of a class template shall be defined in every translation unit in which it is implicitly instantiated **unless the corresponding specialization is explicitly instantiated in some translation unit**; no diagnostic is required.

In your example, `A::g<int>` is implicitly instantiated in `main.cpp` but it is explicitly instantiated in "some translation unit" (`A.cpp`). The program is fine.